# Clojure code static analysis tools

Tags: clojure, conventions

Is there a tool to run code convention tests in clojure?  For example, make sure function names don't have any capital letters or keywords don't have any underscores in them.

Comment: Yep, it is called grep (/ack/the silver searcher) ;-)

Comment: If you develop Web applications, I also want to suggest you to look at this 2 Leiningen plugins: https://github.com/vbauer/lein-jshint and https://github.com/vbauer/lein-jslint
They allow you to check your JS files using corresponding tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two useful [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) plugins I learned about recently:

- [lein-bikeshed](https://github.com/dakrone/lein-bikeshed)
- [lein-kibit](https://github.com/jonase/kibit)

Comment: Also this one looks promising, although I haven't tried it yet: https://github.com/jonase/eastwood

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party here. Seconding [noahlz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7507/noahlz), the three main static analysis tools that I use on a regular basis are [lein-bikeshed](https://github.com/dakrone/lein-bikeshed), [lein-kibit](https://github.com/jonase/kibit), and [Eastwood](http://github.com/jonase/eastwood), though I also use [yagni](http://github.com/venantius/yagni). Each of these has different strengths.

Bikeshed is good for general code cleanup but is mostly focused on style (e.g. making sure lines aren't too long, there's no trailing whitespace, functions have docstrings, etc.).

Kibit is good for showing you the most idiomatic function to use (for instance, when using an `if` form that returns nil if false, you could just use `when` instead).

Eastwood is probably the most comprehensive lint tool that exists for Clojure, and checks for a pretty impressive number of code smell issues.

Finally, Yagni is great for finding unused code paths in your libraries and applications.